# Azure Mobile Service (node backend) __updatedAt property not automatically set after edit

Tags: node.js, azure-mobile-services

After reading the documentation I was expecting that this field is automatically set by Azure Mobile Services. Apparently it isn't.

Should I configure something extra?

Other options that I see (to do for each table):
* add an axtra line to the node js update(item, user, request) function:
      item.__updatedAt = new Date();
* create an update trigger in the database

Anybody experience with this?
Thx!

Answer (score 3):

The __updatedAt column is updated by a trigger created in the underlying SQL Server database, so it should be updated any time a row is updated. Note that this requires a database operation to occur for it to be updated.